# How To Change drop_element in Plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop, plupload

I am using plupload version 2.0. For Drag and Drop I have given the element id let say container1. On some Javascript event I want to change the dragAndDrop container holding the plugin object. 
I tried changing the property dynamically using `uploader.setting.drop_element=$('#container2')`, but didn't get the expected result. Searched on the web but not able to find a working solution.Is there any alternative way to solve the problem? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates your issue ?

Comment: Seeing the plupload code, i don't think you can do that easily without rewriting plupload files. It might be best to create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    drop_element : $('container2')
})
```

Comment: Its like creating a new uploader instance. I want to override the previous one only

Comment: Invoking browse dialog programmatically - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182019/manually-trigger-open-file-dialog-using-plupload

Answer (score 0):

this(uploader instance).settings.drop_element = "new dom element" dynamically will change the drop_element