# TinyMCE insert image - browse button does nothing when clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, tinymce

I'm using the tinyMCE editor, and I've included the insert image button on the toolbar, but when I click the browse button nothing happens! I just get this error "TypeError: p is undefined"

here's the configuration file for tinyMCE:

```
tinyMCE_GZ.init({
    // plugins: 'style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras',
    themes: 'simple,advanced,searchreplace',
    languages: 'en',
    disk_cache: true,
    debug: false
});

tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    skin: "o2k7",
    plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
    // Theme options
    //theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,template,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,undo,redo,|,image,media,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,print",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,|,image,media",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,

    file_browser_callback: "openBrowser",


    // Skin options
    skin: "o2k7",
    //skin_variant: "Blue",
    content_css: "../../Scripts/tiny_mce/themes/simple/skins/o2k7/content.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url: "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url: "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url: "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url: "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values: {
        username: "Some User",
        staffid: "991234"
    },

    //To prevent having new paragraph each line
    force_br_newlines: true,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    forced_root_block: '', // Needed for 3.x

    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onActivate.add(function (ed) {
            cursorRange = ed.selection.getRng();
        });

        ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
            //To Update cursor location when arrows, PgUp , PgDwn , Home & End keys are pressed
            if (e.keyCode >= 33 && e.keyCode <= 40) {
                cursorRange = ed.selection.getRng();
            }
        });

        ed.onInit.add(function (ed) {
            ed.focus();
            cursorRange = ed.selection.getRng();
        });

        ed.onActivate.add(function (ed) {
            ed.focus();
            cursorRange = ed.selection.getRng();
        });

        ed.onClick.add(function (ed, e) {
            cursorRange = ed.selection.getRng();
        });
    },


    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "none"

});
```

How can I enable it?

Thanks.

Comment: does it work without the use of the compressor: tinyMCE_GZ  ?

Comment: I've just tried it without the tinyMCE_GZ, and got the same result!

Comment: i created a tinymce fiddle and it works: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/N3caab/1  . can you include the tiny_mce_dev.js instead of the tiny_mce.js? - this leads to better debugging messages (readable js-errors)

Comment: I've tried to run the fiddle and it didn't work!
I got "f not defined" error!

Comment: what browser and version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: I've tried it on IE9,FF and chrome!
tinyMCE version is 2.1

Comment: sry, i have no problems running the fiddle with IE8, FF16 and Chrome

Comment: Thanks anyway.
But if you have to know any javascript or jQuery function that opens a browse dialog that will be a great help.

Thanks again.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463439/how-to-open-a-file-browse-dialog-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The tinymce version you are using is more that five years old(!!!) and pretty outdated. It won't work with any newer browser. You will need to download a more recent version of tinymce and use that one.

Comment: Sorry! the version I'm using is 3.5.7 that was by mistake.