# How to open a File Dialog or Browse Files Window using Scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, file-browser

I like to show an image or any elements of html and initialize a height to it. When i used a file type of input in html behind of an image like this :

```
<img src="image.png">
<input type="file" name="image" id="booksimage" style="opacity: 0">
```

So input element disappeared and when I clicked on image File Open Dialog opened but it works in a height of a normal input element. when I set a height of 100px to input element it dose not work more than.

When I see that problem of html, I decided to Use Javascript or Jquery to solve problem, I searched an find some similar issues like :

[How to open a file / browse dialog using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463439/how-to-open-a-file-browse-dialog-using-javascript)

but solution is for special browsers and firefox doesn't support it.
Is there any other way for open File Browser Dialog by clicking on an image?!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily browser don't allow to open the browse file dialog without the specific event triggered by the click on an *input* tag with *type="file"* There are some ways to work aorund this, but it won't surely work on every browser you've got.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
#file-image {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#file-image input {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
}

</style>
<div id="file-image">
    <input type="file">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" width="40" height="40" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a couple of years late, but here's is a way of doing it without any Javascript and it's also compatible with any browser.

```html
<label>
  Open file dialog
  <input type="file" style="display: none">
</label>
```

In case you find problems, you may need to use the `for` attribute in the `label` pointing to the `id` of the input.