# Can't trigger onchange event in page load using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

Currently I have a link NEW IMAGE with the following code.

```
<a class="cmpn_image" href="javascript:void(0);" id="new_page_image">NEW IMAGE</a> 

 /* Associated function */
 $("#new_page_image").click(function() { 
          imgType = 'NPG';
          $("#uptext_new_page").trigger('click');
 });
```

On clicking the link, it will open the file upload window.

Now what I need is to trigger the same file input on the page load if a value is present in the url. Below shown is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var param=getparamvalue('p');   // function for getting url paramater
    if(param=='new')
    {                                // upto this is working fine
        $("#uptext_new_page").trigger('change');   // not working; here if the paramter is present the file upload window should come triggering the file input
    }
});
</script>

<div style="visibility:hidden;">
    <form method="post">
      <input type="file" name="name" id="uptext" onChange="ajaxUpload(this.form,'imageUpload.php?filename=name&amp;maxSize=9999999999&amp;maxW=1000&amp;relPath=uploads/images/&amp;colorR=255&amp;colorG=255&amp;colorB=255&amp;maxH=400','uploadProgress','&lt;br /&gt;&lt;img src=\'images/loader_light_blue.gif\' width=\'128\' height=\'15\' border=\'0\' /&gt;','&lt;img src=\'images/error.gif\' width=\'16\' height=\'16\' border=\'0\' /&gt; Error in Upload.'); return false;" />
    </form>

  <form method="post">
      <input type="file" name="name" id="uptext_new_page" onChange="ajaxUpload(this.form,'imageUpload.php?filename=name&amp;maxSize=9999999999&amp;maxW=1000&amp;relPath=uploads/reference/&amp;colorR=255&amp;colorG=255&amp;colorB=255&amp;maxH=400','uploadProgress','&lt;br /&gt;&lt;img src=\'images/loader_light_blue.gif\' width=\'128\' height=\'15\' border=\'0\' /&gt;','&lt;img src=\'images/error.gif\' width=\'16\' height=\'16\' border=\'0\' /&gt; Error in Upload.'); return false;" />
    </form>
</div>
```

On page load itself, if the parameter `p` have value as `new`, then the file upload box should be shown. But it is not working.

I also tried with

```
$("#uptext_new_page").change();
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try $(document).on('change','$uptext_new_page',function(){}) bcz same problem face by me and i solve via this change of code

Comment: Try binding your events using jQuery instead of inline: `$('#uptext_new_page').change(function() { ajaxUpload($(this).closest('form;), ...); return false; }).trigger('change');`

Comment: @Affan: That shouldn't be the issue given that the JS is wrapped in `$(document).ready()`, and there is no indication that these fields are added dynamically after the document is ready.

Comment: @Jenz: If you use `$(this).closest('form')`, it will find the form that `this` (meaning the file input) is inside.

Comment: @Jenz: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you do `$('#uptext_new_page').change(function() { var form = $(this).closest('form'); });`, then the 'change' event listener is only bound to the `#uptext_new_page` element, and `$(this).closest('form')` will only find the form that the current element (ie. `#uptext_new_page`) is inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can trigger the file input to open the Choose File dialog without some user interaction. I believe that if the user clicks another element, you can at that time trigger the click event on the file dialog, but I don't think you can do it without some user interaction. See:

- [open file dialog box in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2048026/259457)
- [click on input box to show open file dialog but not click on choose file button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19310450/259457)
- [How to open a File Dialog or Browse Files Window using Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14375174/259457)
- [How open select file dialog via js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16215771/259457)

All of these examples are showing how to trigger the file upload window when the user clicks on another element, but not on page load.

Same thing goes for opening a new window with JavaScript (`window.open()`). If you do this at some random time without user interaction, I believe it gets caught by pop-up blockers. It's probably a similar issue here.

Actually, this question appears to be a duplicate of [Show input file dialog on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24250877/259457), and the answer there is similar to mine (can't do it without user interaction).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `click`, lets give a try with

```
$("#uptext_new_page").trigger('click');
```

or even you can try on creating a hidden button for click event like

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="file" name="name" id="uptext_new_page" onChange="ajaxUpload('something here'); return false;" />
  <input type="button" style="display:none;" onclick="ajaxUpload('something here'); return false;" id="uptext_new_page_bnt">
</form>
```

And in your jQuery try like

```
$('#uptext_new_page_bnt').trigger('click');
```

Comment: @Gautam..I tried that too. But not working.

Comment: @Gautam..This is also not working with file upload. I tried just echoing a text on triggering click. That is working. But file upload window is not showing.

Comment: I tried by adding a button and on page load triggering the click of button. On click function of button I have triggered click of file input. But that is also not working.