# HTML Click() does not work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine

Hello I have difficulties making the .Click() command work on all browsers, it does work on IE, but not in FF, Chrome.

SCENARIO:
Unity project, scene has a button inside of it. when the button is pressed, A javascript function is called.

Inside that function I have `document.getElementById("file").click();`

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:

when the javascript function is called, i need to open a local file-browser dialogue 
( `<input id="file" type="file">` )

pressing a button and calling "file" works on all browsers. but trying to call a click command on  type does not seems to work in FF, Chrome. Is there any alternatives?
any work around? Thanks.

JUST TO CLARIFY, THERE IS NO USER INPUT ON THE WEBPAGE, the only thing i get is a javascript function that gets called inside html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a file / browse dialog using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463439/how-to-open-a-file-browse-dialog-using-javascript)

Comment: Right, `click()` is not part of the standard. Instead of simulating a click, just do what the click would have done. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element/15948355#15948355. ALso https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click.

Comment: You can use trigger method of jquery

Comment: trigger = not working in FF, CHROME.
Cant get the mouse event to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your observation calling .click() is not supported in Internet explorer. The usual approach to this is to make the file input element have a low opacity and position it over the button.

you can see the details of this approach here

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 0):

.click is not a function in javascript to listen click event. 
To listen event for IE we use

```
.attachEvent
```

and for other browser we use

```
.addEventListener
```

i have made sample example, this code will work for all browser

```js
window.onload=function()
  {
   var a=document.getElementById("abc");
    myAttachEvent(a, "click",onClickMethod ); 
  };
  function myAttachEvent(element, type, handler) {
       if (element.addEventListener) {
           element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
       }else if (element.attachEvent) {
          element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler)
       } else {
            element['on' + type] = handler;
       }
  }
  function onClickMethod(){
   alert("clicked");
  }
```

```css
div{
   background: green;
   height:100px;
   width:100px;
   
  }
```

```html
<div id="abc"></div>
```

Comment: But he doesn't want to **listen** for the click, he wants to **do** the click. Also, minor point, but it is not correct to say "To listen event for IE"; it should be "to listen event for *obsolete versions of* IE".