# IE - File Input Gains Focus, Loses Value on Submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, file, input

I have an input type=file that is clicked by the onclick event of a button.

When the form containing this input is submitted, IE 10 has issues - the file input gains focus AND loses its value - and the form is not submitted.

Edit: The file browser does open, and it does gain the value, it just loses it on submission.

I'm hoping for a solution, if not, a different method of achieving the same results.

Here is the code:

```
<form action=".." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <button type="button" onclick="$('#file').click();">Upload File</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In actuality I have #file hidden (hence the .click()), but I know that's not the issue, because I tested it with #file visible as well. I think the .click() is causing the problem somehow, but I need a workaround.

Comment: File inputs generate their own buttons. Why are you adding yours?

Comment: It has to be styled in a particular way. By hiding the file input and using the button with the onclick, this is achieved easily... Save for this error.

Comment: Have you cross-browser tested this? i'm pretty sure some browsers are very picky in allowing other inputs to open an open file dialog when the file input is hidden.

Comment: might want to take this approach:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2048060/1167867

Comment: It works in Chrome. Not in IE10. Not sure about earlier IEs.

Comment: @ScottCompton -- Definitely check earlier versions (IE9 especially)

Answer (score -2):

If you want your upload button to be styled try this
" input style
     
     
       "