# How to handle properly shortcut "Ctrl+O" for opening files on a web-page in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I'm working on porting some js code that works correctly in Chrome to Firefox. I have a following function for reading files from a file system:

```
function chooseFilesToOpen() {
    var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
    fileInput.type = 'file';
    fileInput.multiple = true;
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
        openFiles(fileInput.files);
    });

    fileInput.click();
}
```

The function is bound to a button on a page (`$('#open-button').click(chooseFilesToOpen)`) and to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> shortcut (there's a switch statement for different keys). The function is invoked in both cases, upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and a button click, but a file browsing dialog appears only in the latter. When I debug it, the dialog pops up when `fileInput.click()` is executed. The same statement seems to do nothing when the function is called from a `keypress` event handler. So, the question is how to make it work for both actions and in both browsers?

Comment: How does it work when you do not even add it to the document?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589994/how-to-open-programmatically-the-file-dialog-box-in-firefox

Comment: @epascarello, it's strange indeed that it works not being added to the document. I found another question close to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032610/javascript-intercepted-ctrlo-does-not-open-my-file-dialog. It seems that it's not possible to simulate keyboard events that call file dialog in FF.
I guess the question should be closed as a duplicate