# Is there a way to count how many files are in a folder and then import it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call the number of files in a folder into a variable so that I can set the array size into that number.

Is this possible using JS and HTML?

I've found a piece of code that might be useful. However I don't understand it well, is it useful to the function I visioned? How?

```
const fs = require('fs');
var dir = '../imgvids';

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

The intended porpuse is to create a variable and set the array size to it, so that then i can create a function that concatenates 'video' + 'i++' (i=0) and to stop at the size of the array so i can make a playlist of videos that autoplay muted.

Comment: You cannot access filesystem from HTML and JS only unless you use some backend programming languages like Node.js, PHP, Java, Python, etc

Comment: You could use the `readdir` function to directly create an array of all the file paths or names.(Yeah, only in Node.js) Why do you want to create an empty array of that length?

Comment: [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048026/open-file-dialog-box-in-javascript) might be of help since in order to work with files in a webpage you'd have to prompt the user with a filedialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *fs-finder* module in *Node.js*.

Here is a [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-finder/v/1.2.0)

```
let Finder = require('fs-finder');

let finder = new Finder('./path/dir');

let files = finder.recursively().findFiles();

console.log(files);
```

This will log all the files inside directories and subdirectories