# How can I load numbers from .txt file to a matrix (float numbers) in Javascript? (without using node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a matrix in a .txt file, e.g.:

### 1 3 4 5 1

### 4 2 5 1 3

### 2 4 5 6 7

### 5 2 5 2 7

### 2 2 6 4 7

And I want to put it into a matrix (as float variable) in JavaScript (without node.js).

Comment: Did you try to solve this exercise yourself?

Comment: This is actually 2 questions; the first part of the question is "how to read a file in js, without nodejs"
The second is "how to convert a string with newlines and spaces to a matrix"
I suggest you to split this question in 2 separate ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [**FileReader**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object to read the contents of the file.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
```

Then when the file is loaded, using the [**.result**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result) property, you can read the content of the files.

```
var text = reader.result;
```

Now, the data from the text file will be in strings format.

```
1 3 4 5 1
4 2 5 1 3
2 4 5 6 7
5 2 5 2 7
2 2 6 4 7
```

You need to read each line check for [**\n**](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/52f31477282ae3c473002317)(which is newline)

Below is the demo code:

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var node = document.getElementById('output');
    node.innerText = text;
    console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
    let array = reader.result.trim().split("\n").map(str => str.trim().split(" "))
    console.log(array)

  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the file as a string you can use this piece of code to parse it into a twodimensional array:

```js
var fileContents = "1 3 4 5 1\n4 2 5 1 3\n2 4 5 6 7\n5 2 5 2 7\n2 2 6 4 7";

var array = fileContents.trim().split("\n").map(str => str.trim().split(" "))

console.log(array);
```

As for loading the file, I'd suggest something like this [Open file dialog box in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048026/open-file-dialog-box-in-javascript)