# input type="file" auto click

Tags: javascript

How do I automatically open the browse dialog of an input type="file" when the page first opens?

Comment: do you need a browser agnostic solution or can you target a specific one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829774/jquery-simulating-a-click-on-a-input-typefile-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you should do this. If you've ever visited a MySpace page, you know how frustrating it can be when a web page activates things on its own when the page loads.

Don't violate how the UI is supposed to work, let the user ask for the dialog.

Besides, if the users instinctively closes it like a popup, and then realizes they needed it, it may not be obvious how they should get the dialog back. Then they will reload the page just to show the dialog again -- all frustrating things you could be avoiding.

That being said, I'm not sure why you want to do this in the first place. This is just my first reaction to what you're asking.

Comment: I totally agree with you Carson

Comment: there might be valid reasons for that! for example you click on a button which is named "upload" and then there opens a modal window where you can see and edit your chosen image before uploading. but you don't want to have another (and ugly) "upload" button in the modal window.

Answer (score 4):

This is completely impossible in Firefox.

In other browsers, you can:

```
document.getElementById('inputId').click();
```

Comment: @Diodeus: Because Firefox doesn't support it.

Comment: And in IE, forms whose file upload buttons have been clicked by script won't submit properly either. The whole idea is basically a dead loss.

Comment: It's possible now in Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1):

fire the click event on the button on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonid").click();
});
```

Comment: Let's not make outlandish assumptions, now. Try `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: it also works on chrome, let me see if i can fix it for firefox