# Trigger FileUpload with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I want to trigger a hidden fileupload and it works fine - except in Apple's Safari browser.
any idea?

```
<input style="position: absolute; display: none;" id="fufile" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<a href="#"  onclick="$('#fufile').click();return false;">open dialog</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4W4XY/

Comment: Which OS? It works for Safari under Windows...

Comment: Then it seems to be working as expected...

Comment: for me it works, when i remove the css-property "display: none;" otherwise it happens nothing. can you confirm this?

Comment: No, it works right off the bat for me.

Answer (score 0):

This other post may help you.

[Programmatically trigger "select file" dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595389/programmatically-trigger-select-file-dialog-box)

You need to use visibility:hidden instead of display:none.

Answer (score -3):

use this code:

```
$('#fufile').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You can also use ```$('#fufile').click();``` as it's a standard event.