# JavaScript click event in promise then

Tags: javascript, promise, dom-events

I've run accross a strange behaviour of the click event I can (more or less) figure out but I can't find documentation about.

Is it possibile to click a button using method click() from within a promise then or using a setTimeout function?

Here's an example to show what I mean:

```
document.getElementById("mioBottone").addEventListener("click", function () {
    callAPI().then(function (data) {
        document.getElementById("inputFile").click();
    });
});

function callAPI () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        $.get( "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/", function( data ) {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

From my tests it looks like click can be only executed in click event listener context and not delayed using promises or setTimeout, but I haven't found any documentation about it.

And here's a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gpeek6s8/23/

Comment: It's not a trusted event

Comment: @TanDuong It doesn't resolve my problem besides I don't have to return `$.get` as I'm wrapping the call to API in a promise and calling `resolve` when I get data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595389/programmatically-trigger-select-file-dialog-box