# Why can't I trigger input file through prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to open a selection of files, but through passing prop to component (I need this for convenience). Is there a way to do this?

https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/RBejRV?editors=1010

Variant in code below does not suit me:

```
  <input type="file" ref="input" hidden>

  <button @click="() => { $refs.input.click() }">Choose file</button>
```

Why does it click but does not open file selection?

```
this.$refs.input.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('clicked: ', e.target)
})
```

Comment: Would you like to show us how you code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/RBejRV?editors=1010

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583865/38065

Comment: @Bert Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work if it's not triggered from inside the click event.

What you can do is create a method inside your child component that can be called from the parent component within the event listener callback.

```js
const compo = Vue.component("compo", {
  template: '<input type="file" ref="input" hidden>',
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.input.addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log('clicked: ', e.target)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    open() {
      this.$refs.input.click()
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    compo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      propForComponent: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.$refs.compo.open()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<compo ref="compo"></compo>

<button @click="onClick">Choose file</button>
```

See this updated pen: https://codepen.io/WisdomSky/pen/GBYyGL?editors=1010

Comment: Many thanks for help! I think this way parent and child components become coupled. I think using slot is best way to do this: https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/ajQvQd?editors=1010 Or am I wrong?

Comment: Your code return "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined",

Comment: @FernandoTorres that error means you haven't correctly imported Vue.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Your example code inside your  answer return that error

Comment: Because I only used it for the formatting, not an actual working demo. Reading the code should be enough.