# How to programmatically simulate open select file dialog via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, simulation

I need programmatically upload file to web, i think best way is `document.querySelector('#ctl00_uxMainContent_uxProductsImportFileListControl_uxProductsImportFileInfo_uxImportFile').click()` but it not working....

```
<td class="formvalue">
    <span style="width: 450px">
       <input type="file" name="ctl00$uxMainContent$uxProductsImportFileListControl$uxProductsImportFileInfo$uxImportFile" id="ctl00_uxMainContent_uxProductsImportFileListControl_uxProductsImportFileInfo_uxImportFile" style="width:450px;">
       <span id="ctl00_uxMainContent_uxProductsImportFileListControl_uxProductsImportFileInfo_uxImportFileRequiredValidator" title="Needed" style="color:Red;display:none;"><span class="formerrorbox nowrap"><span class="iconformerror">Needed</span></span></span>
       </span>
 </td>
```

Comment: Did you look at this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595389/programmatically-trigger-select-file-dialog-box

Comment: Needs to be a user action to trigger it