# Can not submit with action change of input file by jQuery

Tags: html, dhtml

I want to upload a image when click to a div, it ok in ff, chrome, safari but not working with IE, i don't know why? Please help me! Thanks.

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#photo_box').click(function() {
                $('.upload_button').click();
            });

            $('input[name=f_img]').change(function(event) {
                $('#frm_upload').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100; height: 200px; border:1px solid red;" id="photo_box">Click here</div>
<form id="frm_upload" name="frm_img" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: absolute; left: -1000000px; top: -10100000px; opacity: 0;" target="ifr_img">
    <input type="file" class="upload_button" name="f_img"/>
</form>
<iframe id="ifr_img" name="ifr_img" style="width:200px; height:200px; border: 1px solid blue;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As *bobince* explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829817/786814), it depends on the version and browser you are using and most versions of IE won't allow this (I'm not sure about IE9 though).

You could try the [transparency technique](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=0uXVUYeBaOYC&lpg=PA257&ots=yZegEplVis&dq=transparency%20technique%20file%20upload&pg=PA257#v=onepage&q&f=false) or a Flash-based approach like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for jQuery.

Comment: No, it not working after I choose a file in the files browse. The action 'change' of input file is working but the form is not submit? While don't have problem in ff, chrome and safari...

Comment: Yes @user1265546, that's what _bobince_ explains: "the form won't actually submit"