# JQuery dialog / submit() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

Works everywhere except IE8. The submit never fires. I tried taking out the dialog and just leaving the submit but still nothing happens in IE8.

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#fileUpload").click(function () {
        $("#fileButton").click();
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#fileButton").change(function () {
        $("#dialogUploading").dialog({
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            modal:true,
            async:true
        });
        $("#formSubmit").submit();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
        using (Html.BeginForm("ReferralUpload", "ReferralNetwork", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "formSubmit", style = "display:inline" }))
        {
            <input type="file" id="fileButton" name="fileButton" style="display:none" />
            <button type="button" id="fileUpload" style="width:250px;">Upload Referrals</button>
        }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing `$("#fileButton").change(function () {` to `$("#fileButton").change(function (e) {` and see if that makes a difference?  I think IE needs the event passed for it to be happy.

Oh, and do the same for `$("#fileUpload").click(function () {` to `$("#fileUpload").click(function (e) {`

Comment: Still no go. The dialog appears (which it did before I added the e parameter), but no submit

Comment: @DontFretBrett: but it works in other browsers?  I don't have an environment set up where I can test your code exactly. I can't even get the basics to work in chrome, though.

Comment: open up developer tools in IE8... see if anything is showing up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct version of jQuery.
Version 2 and above aren't compatible with IE8.

http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: We're using jquery 1.10.2 and jquery ui 1.10.3

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I discovered it can't be done [jQuery : simulating a click on a <input type="file" /> doesn't work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829774/jquery-simulating-a-click-on-a-input-type-file-doesnt-work-in-firefox). Not without some hackery. In IE8 the file input can't be programatically clicked or it won't submit. One hack is to set the opacity to zero and have an image over the button:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html