# How to click a link on a website that executes JavaScript to open a FileDialogue?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

I am creating an application in C# that will navigate a website.

This website allows me to upload files and that is where I get stuck.

When you browse the website there are several links that say "New document" and all of the links are the same in terms of HTML, nothing really specifies anything until you get to the base URI, then there is some hashes and some other things.

My question is, how do I "click" the link to present me with the filedialogue box?

Here is some of the code:

```
<input type="file" name="m$c$ctl00$ucFileUpload" id="m_c_ctl00_ucFileUpload" class="fileUpload" onchange="if (typeof(parent.DFU) !== 'undefined') { parent.DFU.OnUploadBegin('p_lt_ctl07_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_DocumentLibrary_libraryElem_uploadAttachment_containerDiv'); __doPostBack('m$c$ctl00$btnHidden',''); }" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; outline: none; right: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 279px; opacity: 0;">
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: There are several techniques to do this, follow [this link][1] or this [solution for firefox][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829774/jquery-simulating-a-click-on-a-input-type-file-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't help me. I am using C# and the WebBrowser tool to open the website, then I need to click the first "New document" link. I am having trouble getting that link to execute.I've tried several methods but nothing has worked.