# Angular 2 trigger file upload in parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

i want to trigger file upload in router parent component. It should call two functions that are present in parent, `openFileSelect` and `uploadSelectedFile` to control the `<input type="file">` element.

My router looks like this:

```
{ 
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthService],
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/dashboard',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'upload',
            component: UploadComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

The file input is in HomeComponent.html template and router-outlet where the child component is displayed:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" #fileUpload>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then in HomeComponent.ts i have:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "home.component.html",
})
export class HomeComponent {

    filesToUpload: Array<File>;

    constructor() {
        this.filesToUpload = [];
    }

    openFileSelect() {
        // TODO - How to programmatically trigger click event on <input type="file"> ?
    }

    uploadSelectedFile() {
        this.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:3000/upload", [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
             console.log(result);
        }, (error) => {
             console.error(error);
        });
    }

    fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
        this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>> fileInput.target.files;
    }

    makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>) {
        ... XHR request ...
    }
}
```

At the end i want to trigger the same openFileSelect method from HomeComponent inside UploadComponent

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "upload.component.html",
})
export class UploadComponent {

    constructor() { }

    openFileSelectInHomeComponent() {
        // TODO - how to call HomeComponent.openFileSelect() ?
    }
}
```

So i have two questions:

- How to programmatically trigger click event on ?
- And how to call function from child component to router parent component?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar answer to your question here:
[jQuery : simulating a click on a <input type="file" /> doesn't work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829774/jquery-simulating-a-click-on-a-input-type-file-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Maybe it will give you an idea.  Or you can use a UI control like primeNg's FileUpload control.

Comment: I have achieved that if i click on one button to trigger file upload click event but that is not my goal. I want to trigger it by calling a function, for example when user enters all the data it would trigger file input dialog. The way i have achieved that is with mentioned `#fileUpload` reference variable. My problem is that i dont know how to send event to that variable inside components function. It should go somehow with `@ViewChild` decorator, but i had no success.