# Save File Dialog Box in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a virtual path to a .wav file. I stored that value in a  hidden field. Now when clicking a button i want to show a save dialog box for that virtual path .

i tried this

```
    window.open(path, "", "");
```

But it opens file in media player .I just want to show save dialog so that u ser can select a place to store that file. Is it possible using jquery?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 introduces a new attribute, `download`, that allows you to do this. Here's an example with an anchor tag:

```
<!-- On click opens a 'Save Dialog' for the href specified, and uses the filename specified in the download tag. -->
<a href="http://example.com/path/to/my/file.txt" download="file.txt" />
```

Triggering the download using JavaScript:

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
document.getElementById("anchor").dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```