# JavaScript: Getting notification when empty iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to dynamically create an iframe with a `<form>` and form child `<input>` element in it using jQuery. For some reason, the `load` event of the iframe is never firing, so I can't add the `<input>`. What am I missing?

Very short: http://jsfiddle.net/LLKej/10/

**EDIT: I'm trying to detect when the *iframe* loads**

Comment: You want to place the INPUT element onto the document that has loaded into the IFRAME?

Answer (score 0):

read the console. there is no load event for forms.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no onload or load event for an HTML form. The only available actions besides the typical events like click, focus, and change, are submit and reset.

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement#Methods

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event *is* firing (confirm by placing an alert inside of your load event). However, you are not appending content to the `iframe` properly:

```
$iframe.load(function() {

    var $uploadForm =  $("<form target='" + iframeName + "' action='" + options.postUrl + "' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' />");

    $iframe.contents().find("body").append($uploadForm);
    $uploadForm.append($("<input type='file' value='" + options.file + "' />"));

    if (options.selectFile === true) {
         $uploadForm.find("input").click();   
    } 
});
```

Note the call to `.contents()` before the `append` call.

Additionally, I don't believe it's possible to programmatically launch a file input's browse functionality (confirmed by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210643/497356)).