# iframe .click() and .trigger() won't work in firefox v 4 below

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I have an iframe on  my site, in the iframe I put a button to trigger the

```
<input type="file">
```

These are the elements:

> button id="click"
> input type="file" id = "file"

This is the script code:

```
 $("#click").click(function() {
$('#file').trigger('click');
 });
```

I also replace the `.trigger` into `.click();` but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove commas.Try like this

assign button id="click1"

```
 $("#click1").click(function() {
$("input").trigger('click');
 });
```

Comment: tnx.., but my original code dont really have a comma:,


this is my origginAL code

     $("#click, #click label").click(function() {
 $('#file').trigger('click');
 });

Comment: ive found this post.., 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input-e

Comment: it works fine on fire fox....just paste above code inside body tag after the<input type="file"/>