# Cross browser open file browse dialog

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I've been looking for that holy grail - nice file dialogs in HTML. I've come up with a solution that uses jQuery to `click()` the (hidden) file element when a button is clicked. This works fine in FireFox 4, but Chrome and Opera fail. Changing the `click()` to `focus()` worked for Chrome, but nothing in Opera works. I haven't tested IE, but I don't want to ragequit life quite yet.

Here is the current code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="formFile" id="profileImgContainer">
    <input type="file" name="profileImg" id="profileImg">

    <label>Profile Picture</label>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="profileImgText"><input type="button" id="profileImgButton" value="Choose File">
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".formFile input[type='file']").live('change', function()
{
    $(this).parents(".formFile").find("input[type='text']").val($(this).val());
});

$(".formFile input[type='button']").live('click', function()
{
    $(this).parents(".formFile").find("input[type='file']").click();
});

$(".formFile input[type='text']").live('click', function()
{
    $(this).parents(".formFile").find("input[type='file']").click();
});
```

Can anyone offer a cross browser way of opening the file dialog using jQuery/JavaScript? I don't want to use the transparent element trick due to the need to have input interactions (CSS `:hover`) etc.

Comment: +1 for `I don't want to ragequit life quite yet` :-)

Comment: Thanks andyb. IE is the bane of my existence. If it went into a hole and died (or was replaced by FF, Chrome, sausages on a plate, etc) then I and every other web developer out there would be so much happier!

Comment: could not agree more! BTW, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input-e/3030174#3030174

Comment: I just closed another tab with that in it, so I'll say yes ;-) I'm having a read now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$(this).parents(".formFile").find("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
```

Comment: This now has FF4 and Chrome functioning nicely, but Opera 11.11 doesn't want to play nice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This might be some years late, but here's is a way of doing it without any Javascript and it's also cross browser.

```html
<label>
  Open file dialog
  <input type="file" style="display: none">
</label>
```

In case you find problems, you may need to use the for attribute in the label pointing to the id of the input.

Comment: I think this is the most clever answer I've ever seen on StackOverflow.