# Open a file dialog when parent div is clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, file, input

I want to open a file dialog when the parent div is clicked. If I click the first parent div, it should only open the first input file.

```
<div class="fileupload">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
</div>

<div class="fileupload">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="attachement" />
</div>
```

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460185/cross-browser-open-file-browse-dialog

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just trigger the `click` event on the `input` element:

```
$('.fileupload').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('input[type="file"]').click();
});

$('.fileupload input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EctCK/**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, When i try this, i'm getting this error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } '

Comment: @user1915190: That's a syntax error somewhere in your script.

Comment: When I click the div, my browser is crashed

Comment: My scenario was a little different but this answer really helped me to shape my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/),

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).parents(".fileupload").find("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, When I click the parent div, my browser got crashed

Comment: try again and try with other browsers