# Modifying browse button, chrome browser

Tags: html, forms, button

I've made a form, for uploading an image, it works good on IE,Firefox.
But on chrome the browse button doesn't work.

This is the browse button:

```
<input type="button" name="brw" id="brw" onClick="img.click()" />
```

When you click this button you fire up img fields browse function.

Other fields:

```
<input name="img" type="file" value="" style="display: none;" onChange="txtFilename.value = this.value;" />
```

And when you select the image you get images name in this disabled text field.

```
<input type="text" name="txtFilename" id="txtFilename" disabled="disabled" />
```

Any solution for crossbrowser, would save my life :) .
Thx all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://jsbin.com/ayoxad/7/edit#javascript,html,live) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input-e/3030174#3030174) (second answer). Input of file type cannot be hidden, by setting `display: none` you have to hide it in another way. In my example I set `visibility: hidden` or you can play with opacity (like in the other answer).

Comment: Thx mate, I was wondering that function isn't being accepted by chrome or selection but it was about display, as you said.

Comment: wait until I get enough reputation