# Jquery click on new input

Tags: jquery, input, click, append

Hy,

I have a small problem with jQuery

When I add a new input field, i can't use the click function on it :

```
var input = $('<input name="image" type="file"/>');
$(this).append(input);
input.click();
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to bind a handler on the click or are you trying to trigger a click event?

Comment: your code works, it executes the click function on an input type file element, here it opens a browse window to select a file.  what do you want to achieve actually?  binding something to be done when clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input-e)

Comment: This does work. Can you be more specific how it doesn't?

Comment: actually this doen't work on chrome...

Answer (score 1):

If you attach a click event handler to the new `input`, it will work fine:

```
var input = $('<input name="image" type="file"/>');
input.click(function() {
   //Do something
});
$(this).append(input);
input.click();
```

If on the other hand you want the new `input` to pick up an event handler that's been defined previously, you will have to use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) when you attach the event initially (this example attaches a click event handler to all `input` elements, including ones that get added to the DOM later, like yours):

```
$("input").live("click", function() {
   console.log("other clicked"); 
});
```

Comment: it's seems that google chrome is my problem....

this is not working on chrome:

 `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $('#tt').click();
 });
 </script>
 <input name="image" type="file" id="tt"/>`

but this yes...

 `<input name="image" type="file" id="tt"/><input type="button" id="test" onclick="$('#tt').click()"/>`

thanks google.... any idea to fix chrome problems?