# Open all Link with specific class in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

For example if i have code like this:

javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('SomeClass'); 
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
   inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

that can click on all inputs in page with "SomeClass" 
is it possible to do it for link with specific class and open them all in new tabs?

Comment: not able to understand what you are actually asking????

Answer (score 0):

```
element.trigger('click');
```

but it is not supported on all browser. take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991665/2696626

and this for handler:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Edit:

try this code in [this](http://www.gustosms.com) site:

```
$("a").each(function(){ $(this).click(); });
```

Comment: i don't understand how to use it , im inserting the code in chrome console

Answer (score 0):

Element.trigger() is jQuery. You should be looking into dispatchEvent (most browsers) and fireEvent (IE). Or as suggested you can start using jQuery and use trigger.