# How do I display the file selection popup in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

You know how a file selection browser popup opens when you click on an HTML input element with type `file`? Can I trigger that popup to appear in javascript?

At a certain point in my javascript, I'd like for the popup to appear so that user can upload a text file. Then, I plan to turn the file blob data into an arraybuffer with the HTML5 FileReader API.

I've tried triggering the popup by faking a click to a file input element to no avail:

```
// Does not work.
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'file';
input.click();
```

How can I write a javascript function to trigger the file selection popup? I know that I can instead rely on an HTML5 drag and drop interface for uploading files, but I prefer the popup.

Comment: As far as I know, It's not possible due to a security reason. Or some browser allow it, but browser compatibility isn't guaranteed. You might want to take a look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: A possible answer for you here by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15876384/1664330

Answer (score 0):

The element is created but not added to the DOM.

You should add it to another element