# jquery trigger event not working with Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, datatables

I trying download PDF through Datatable in Safari browser but .trigger() event is not working. It working properly with chrome and mozilla firefox

Here is HTML code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tablePDF"  class="tableExportOption">  Export as PDF </a>
```

Java Script

```
$('#tablePDF').on('click', function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
            var table;
            table = tables[i];
            table.button( '0-0' ).trigger();
        } 
   });
```

where "tables" is array type of varible where i pushed datatable properties.

Kindly provide solution.

Comment: It's working on my safari. would you check that in that trigger function is triggering or not to add a alert.

Comment: Does safari version effects ? i am working with  safari version of 5.1.7

Comment: mine also 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery trigger click not working on safari browsers in mac, Ipad & Iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928386/jquery-trigger-click-not-working-on-safari-browsers-in-mac-ipad-iphone)