# Livewire model binding while clicking other element

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I have a very simple problem. Whenever I click on div I want the `data binding` to be applied to the file input.

```
<div>click me</div>
<input type="file" wire:model="photo"> <!-- while clicking on div, it should do the data binding to this file input  -->
```

I have been searching for it in the documentation but couldn't find any clue. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: you want to open the input file when you click on the div?

Comment: @haruk1515 Exactly

Comment: you can do the same with label right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okei i was searching and testing, to see if i can acomplish that, and there is a solution with jquery:

```
<div id="trigger">click me</div>
<input type="file" id="file_input" wire:model="photo">

$("#trigger").unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
    $("#file_input").click();
});
```

i will give credit where i found the answer:

[triggering a file input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977497/triggering-a-file-input-button)

if your idea is to use livewire only, you could create a function

```
public function fileTrigger(){
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('TriggerFilem');
}
```

add this to js:

```
window.addEventListener('TriggerFilem', e => {
    $("#trigger").unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
        $("#file_input").click();
});
});
```

and in the view:

```
<div wire:click="fileTrigger()" id="trigger">click me</div>
<input type="file" id="file_input" wire:model="photo">
```

Edit:

If you don't want to use jquery, i was testing a solution on js only:

```
document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener("click",() => {
    document.getElementById('file_input').click();
    
    });
```

hope it helps!

Comment: It is a good solution but I want it without `jQuery`. Even in second solution the 'jQuery' is being used

Comment: @ZainFarooq i added another solution for js only, without jquery, hope it helps

Comment: I try that. I hope it works