# Javascript file upload hack, not working on all browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

How can I improve the following so it works in multiple browsers?

```
$('#img').click(function() {
     $('input[type=file]').click();
});
```

So when I click an image it will allow to select a file to upload. On the css I did the following:

```
input[type="file"]{display:none;}
```

Tried it on safari 5.1.2 & opera 11.61 and it did not work.... Test it on firefox and ie8 and it worked...

Comment: This might provide some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: inputs with `display:none` may be not handled as common ones and are not submitted by the default form submit. Try using something like `opacity:1%` or wrapper with `overflow:hidden` or overlapping.

Comment: do you try with trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with inputs type file in a x-browser compatible way.

Quirksmode, as always, has a lot to say about this topic:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html