# Open File Dialog box on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have an `Open File` dialog box on a link in my webpage.

I tried

```
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file">
```

but, it works as a button. And, doesn't allow to select multiple files.

I want to have something like

```
<a href="#" onclick="some_function_for_OpenFileDialogBox">Upload Files</a>
```

Please suggest.

Thank You

Kaur

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can only open a "Open File" dialog using a input type=file tag. However the efect you are looking for can be accomplished like this :

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px" multiple />
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('upload').click(); return false">Upload</a>
```

Comment: How do you get the name of the selected file? Thank you!
@d4rkpr1nc3