# Unable to hide the file attachment browse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sending attachments in email, while sending user can actually add multiple attachments. My code is keep displaying the browse button for every time. I want to display only one button and let the user opens the file picker for any no of attachments.
Please tell me whats wrong with my code.
Also see the attached image. Which is something I don't want that behavior.

What I want is on clicking the attach more button it should automatically open the file picker. Currently it is displaying the

Thank you.

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
              <div class="element">
                <label>Attachment</label>
                <span class="upload_file_button"><input type="file" name="upload_file1" id="upload_file1"/></span>
                </div>
                <div id="moreImageUpload"></div>
                <div id="moreImageUploadLink" style="display:none;margin-left: 10px;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="attachMore" class="fa fa-plus"> Attach More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// onclick browse button attach the file id and show the attachmore link

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^='upload_file']").each(function() {
  var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("upload_file", ""));
  $("#upload_file" + id).change(function() { 
   if ($("#upload_file" + id).val() != "") {
   $("#moreImageUploadLink").show();
   }
  });
});
var upload_number = 2;
$('#attachMore').click(function() {
//add more file. Everytime clicking on attachmore link show the browse button also attach more as well.
var moreUploadTag = ''
 moreUploadTag += '<div class="element"><label for="upload_file"' + upload_number + '>Upload File ' + upload_number + '</label>';
 moreUploadTag += '<span class="upload_file_button"><input type="file" id="upload_file' + upload_number + '" name="upload_file' + upload_number + '"/></span>';
 moreUploadTag += '&nbsp;<a href="javascript:del_file(' + upload_number + ')" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="return confirm(\"Are you really want to delete ?\")">Delete ' + upload_number + '</a></div>';
 $('<dl id="delete_file' + upload_number + '">' + moreUploadTag + '</dl>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#moreImageUpload');
 upload_number++;
 });
});

function del_file(eleId) {
 var ele = document.getElementById("delete_file" + eleId);
 ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
}
</script>
```

[image]

**On click *+ Attach More*  it is displaying the browse button. Instead I want to open the file picker right away upon clicking *+ Attach more*.**

Comment: I see no where in your code where you try to open it up. Click the input

Comment: @epascarello No. Every time I click on + Attach more, it is opening the Browse button.
If you tested on jsfiddle it does not work.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216331/open-file-dialog-box-on-a-tag

Comment: @Packer I would test it on JSFiddle if you made one'

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line

```
$('#upload_file'  + upload_number).trigger('click');
```

before

```
 upload_number++;
```

in order to have the "Attach more" button to trigger the opening of the file pickup. 
Then you could hide the input file tag with CSS.

Comment: When I add that line, on attach more it is opening the file picker but it is not showing the file name.