# Dynamically create file input element

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I want to customize the file input button, so I use this code to create an file input element

```
function inputBtn(){
    var input=document.createElement('input');
    input.type="file";
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(input).click();
    },200);
}

<button id="ifile" onclick="inputBtn()">create</button>
```

However, when I click create, it shows nothing.

Comment: You're getting an error, don't you? Also, your code does not try to *show* an input, it only *creates* one.

Comment: You are also not able to click a file input using jquery; it's not possible for security reasons.

Comment: @Daedalus -- input.click(); will execute a click event on the DOM element 'input'

Comment: @user1789573 Have you successfully done that in Firefox?

Comment: @user1789573 Obviously, given this question is 4 years old, it [helps to do your research first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input).  In short: it didn't work at one point; now it does.

Comment: @Daedalus -- Ha! I didn't notice how old it was...good thing things have been updated, i'm glad!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're creating the new DOM element, but you're not attaching it to the DOM.  You need something like:

```
document.getElementById('target_div').appendChild(input);
```

You can see how this works in a poorly done JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JQHPV/2/

Comment: thank you Marc, but I don't want to show this element in front, how this can be done?

Comment: @PandaYang, Add CSS to hide it: `input {display: none}`, and when that works for you, feel free to approve this solution.

Comment: I have tried the css, it won't work, because when the input button is hided, the window that it shows also be hided. I have tried another method, use the width and position to minimize the size of this input element and find a picture overlap it. also thank you for your help.

Comment: @PandaYang, it works just fine for me using Firefox on Windows.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/JQHPV/4/

Comment: document.body.appendChild(input) will add the element to the DOM.  You can even uniquely identify it through its properties (i.e. tagName = "MyUniqueInputTagName");

Comment: @panda you can also add hidden attribute. `input.hidden = true`