# How can I programmatically open the file picker with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In JavaScript can I make a “click” event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

I have naively tried the following to open the file picker programmatically with JavaScript (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fEBFp/)):

```
<input type='file'>​

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input').click();
    });
</script>
```

The above doesn't work. How can I open the file picker of a `input type='file'` with JavaScript?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: jQuery or not, I don't care.

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.

Comment: But your example *is jQuery*? If it doesn't matter, do a native DOM method version as an example.

Comment: [Is this what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC2Ft/).

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? Do you want to hide the default input, so that you can style some other element to trigger the dialog, or why?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson - The OP is trying to hack Chrome for a hacking Chrome prize.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For security reasons you can't trigger the dialog, unless it is as a response to some user triggered event. You could for instance trigger the dialog through a click on some other element:

```
$(function () {
    $(".someElement").click(function () {
        $('#f').click();
    });
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fEBFp/1/).

​

Answer (score 5):

As a security measure, you can only open such dialogs on an user input, such as a click event (on whatever element). You cannot open it randomly such as on page load.

http://jsfiddle.net/fEBFp/2/

Comment: I think it's it's a little odd there's no security exception in the console, though.

Comment: Responding to user input works fine cross-browser, just one thing though. If the file input has `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, the dialog may not open in older browsers. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/fEBFp/3/) using an example of alternative masking without `display`/`visibility` CSS.

Comment: Thank you. In Chrome I put the file input into a 0x0px div now. In Firefox it's not even necessary to insert the file input into the document.