# How to show file dialog with JavaScript once the page is loaded in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to show the file dialog **once the page is loaded**.
**I tried using JS to trigger the click event on the file input in jQuery document ready event.** But this approach only works in IE11, it doesn't work in Chrome (41.0.2272.118).
How can I make it work in Chrome?

Here is my code which doesn't work in Chrome but work in IE:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My HTML File</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <input type="file" id="a" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Go();
        });

        function Go() {
            var input = $('input');
            
            input.click();
            console.log('Gooooooooooooooo');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot, most browsers won't allow you. The file upload dialog can only be displayed as a result of the user actually clicking (or focus -> enter) on a file upload input.

Answer (score 1):

IE will allow you to trigger a .click event on a type='file', but most other browsers will not, for security reasons. However, [there is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) that might work for you.

Comment: I know how to open the file dialog by programmatic triggering the click event. My problem here is this way doesn't work once the page is loaded.

Comment: I found a solution from another stack overflow page [that should work fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134014/how-can-i-programmatically-open-the-file-picker-with-javascript). Accomanying JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fEBFp/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I want the file dialog open automatically after the page is loaded without clicking anything.

Answer (score 0):

No straight ways of triggering it with onload(). 
Onload is only supported by the `<input type = "image">` tag. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp).

+1 @william.taylor.09's proposition.

Comment: I know how to open the file dialog by programmatic triggering the click event. My problem here is this way doesn't work once the page is loaded. 
I'm trying something like $(document).ready(function(){ // trigger the click event on file input.}); but it doesn't work.