# Android: element.click() not working

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to style an input type="file" element by hiding it and creating a link to click the  input element. My code works on an iPhone 5 but not on my Galaxy Nexus (Android).

My code:

```
<input id="files" type="file" accept="image/*;" class="hidden" />
<div id="button" onclick="files.click();">Take picture</div>
```

What do I have to do to make it work on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment on your question, but I do not have enough reputation. There you might find the answer to your question (or rather explanation, why it does not work – security reasons):
[In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

Comment: Fixed it with setting the opacity of the input element to zero :). Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="files.click();"
```

Should be:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('files').click();"
```

But you better use unobtrusive javascript, avoid writing inline javascript code inside the html.

Comment: changing files to document.getElementById('files') didn't work but I will try the unobtrusive javascript :)

Comment: now I do onclick="handleclick();" and function handleclick () {alert('test');files.click();}. The alert works just fine, but the click() still doesn't...

Comment: @PhilippeMaes. I think that some browser won't give you trigger events on a hidden element. try make the input visible and try again, I'm almost sure this is it.