# javascript click element in iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In JavaScript can I make a “click” event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

I wanted to make single click upload so I hide the  `<form>` inside `<iframe>` like this (I just typed `<iframe>` tags around `<form>` to hide the form):

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" height="1" width="1" frameborder="0">
    <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploaded.php">
        <div class="row">
        <label for="file">Select a File to Upload (up to 20MB)</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="40" onchange="uploadFile()" />
        </div>
    </form>
</iframe>
```

Then outside the `<iframe>` I made a button:

```
<div align="center">
    <input type="button" value="Upload" align="center" onclick="browse();" />
</div>
```

the browse() javascript is this:

```
function browse()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById.("iframe");
    var input = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    input.getElementById('file').click();
}
```

but it not working. The browse file dialog does not open. I'm using Firefox 17.
Is there a way to click() on `<input>` inside `<iframe>` or any other one-click upload solution, but still using my uploadFile() AJAX function?

```
function uploadFile() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "uploaded.php");
        xhr.send(fd);
      }
```

EDIT: this is working when the form is not in iframe, so my question is not wheter or not can I use click() on `<input type="file">`. I can and it is working in Firefox 17.
My question is how to use click() on `<input type="file">` inside `<iframe>`.

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain?

Comment: I just put iframe tags around the form inside index.php page. All same file, same domain, no externall source

Comment: Why would you use an iframe like that?

Comment: so i can make it 1px and create button outside for single-click upload.

Comment: You can't programatically `click` an `input:file` element, at least consistently across browsers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: I tried and it works on firefox 17 and that question is not same as mine.

Comment: give me back my point, you added minus for nothing

Answer (score -1):

The JavaScript should be throwing an error since you have a type with an extra `.`

```
var iframe = document.getElementById.("iframe");  
                                    ^-- typo
```

Comment: yes, I corrected and tried, but still not working

Answer (score -1):

The child elements of an `<iframe>` are alternative content to use if the browser doesn't support iframes. They do not form part of the document loaded into the frame (which is what `contentDocument` would access).

Your problem (or at least your first problem) is that you are trying to use that as a hack to hide content. Don't do that.