# How to make a click on <button> element to trigger a file browsing?

Tags: javascript, css

I need a `<button>` element, on which one clicks would trigger a file browsing (ie. the click event of `<input type="file">`). Is there a way to achieve that without affecting the look of the button?

Comment: Why is this downvoted, for cyring outloud?!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: @bvukelic has got a point. It would be greatly appreciated to give out reason when you downvote a post. Otherwise, downvoting becomes a tool to discourage people from asking question, when it should really be a constructive mean to make the community to ask better questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually trigger the click event on the file input.

```
$('button').click(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   $('input[type=file]').click();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UxFM4/2/

Comment: Nice one, I didn't think of that. Have an upvote for dat dislay:none!

Comment: Interesting. Does this work across the mainstream browsers? I am curious if the solution is this simple and straightforward why are there so many html/css hacks I found on the Internet using `<label>` with button-like background image and `<input type="file">` with `opacity: 0`?

Comment: @tamakisquare: Should work. I've tested in FF and Chrome, and both are happy. Don't have access to IE atm. As for why there are hacks out there, beats me. Maybe it's just not that common of a procedure.

Comment: And yeah, sometimes, developers tend to overthink the problem. :)))

Comment: This is really interesting, indeed. I remember I used to be not able to programmatically call `click()` on `<input type="file">` element in Chrome but now I CAN! The world has changed too fast I must say. Let I try this in my own code. Thanks.

Comment: @tamakisquare: There were times when styling just about any form widget was a pain in the butt, you know. :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on css/html hacks, you can just style the input to match the one as the button.

The `type=file` is unique and you can't emulate it to look like a button (since buttons take text in the middle, and don't have a type parameter). If you really need to do it, either with javascript or with css to make it look like a button (to hide the path).

[Fiddle to crop to make it button only and hide the path, (with css you can style it)](http://jsfiddle.net/yZEXu/) Chrome only for this one.

Comment: I need to use my own styled button, so this doesn't really work in my case. Thanks though.

Comment: @tamakisquare: Perfectly valid use case, too.

Comment: @bvukelic - Thanks for the reminder. I overlooked the part that the button of `<input type="file">` can be styled.

Comment: @tamakisquare: Yeah? I wasn't aware of that. Certainly doesn't work for me in FF.

Comment: @bvukelic you can't change the width in firefox, but you can change the height and some other properties, [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/etHze/2/) im clipping the input text and just showing the browse button (firefox only). Just for demonstrating purposes.

Comment: @Wololo: Thanks, but I'd rather stick to the "hide the motherf***er and be done with it" approach. :)

Comment: @bvukelic yes, that is the way to go!