# Calling "Click()" method of an element returns undefined, although the element definitely exists

Tags: javascript, file, input, click, undefined

I'm trying to call the click() method of a file input with a specific id, but the function call returns undefined and basically, nothing happens. I've replicated the situation here: http://jsfiddle.net/gkaG2/

It's very simple:

**HTML**

```
<input id="hiddenFileInput" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" >
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('hiddenFileInput').click();
alert(document.getElementById('hiddenFileInput').click());
```

I try calling the click() method on the element, which doesn't work. I then call alert() to print what the function returns when it's called. It returns "undefined." I'm obviously doing something wrong, but what exactly?

Comment: remove .click() from inside your alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't emulate click on `input type=file`. It's forbidden. It works only inside another onclick handler. The user must click on something to open the dialog.

Comment: From what I understand Riateche, that's not true. Here's a demo provided by Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/file-click-demo.html

Comment: It works only inside another onclick handler. The user must click on something to open the dialog.

Comment: Oh, that would explain a lot. I had it working earlier, but only when a user clicked on a button. Now that I tried to call it when the page loaded, it wasn't working, and I couldn't figure out why for the life of me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security issue. To prevent your Browser to select files for you, you can't simulate click events. See this: [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, Zim84. It turns out it is possible to call the click method on a file input, but as Riateche said, only if the user clicks on something to open the dialog.