# Javascript Only to Invoke HTML color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors

I want a Javascript only solution to invoke the HTML5 color picker

```
<input type="color" />
```

Apparently you can not simulate a click on an input element because of security issues

[In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

If anyone has a work around for this situation it would be really useful in my situation.

---

Note: A Javascript only solution means I can trigger it from the Javascript console without interacting with any HTML elements.

Comment: Of course you can simulate a click or change event on an input, the linked question pertains to inputs with the type "file", where triggering a file upload would be a security risk, not in general ?

Comment: @adeneo seems not to work for input type color in chrome too (not tested other browsers): http://jsfiddle.net/TNmR9/

Comment: @roasted - it probably doesn't, haven't tested it, but as that also opens an external window and relies on built in browser stuff, you probably can't trigger it ?

Comment: How exactly do you want this event to be triggered? I mean, has your user to click somewhere else or you want to open it on completly different event (e.g onload...)?

Comment: I need it to be triggered as a function, as this is a hidden webview within a native mobile app.

Comment: I don't think you can, it's not that it's really a security risk, it's just seems like browsers haven't implemented a way to do this yet ?

Comment: I realize that it seems impossible at this point in time, but I guess this question is for anyone who can find a hack around, or to post an answer when if it becomes possible in the future. I had to remove the functionality I was planning because I assume this won't be answered anytime soon.

Comment: Why would this get downvoted. It's a very good question.