# Input field for uploading

Tags: html, css, blueimp

I am using the blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload basic plugin.
In a form, the input field for uploading files is, by default, on the right of the button.
A text is also written into.
How can I have the field on the left and how can I get rid the text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about is standard browser behavior. When you use `<input type='file'>`, the browser chooses how to render that, and it can give it its own default text like 'Choose file'. I have used a workaround in the past which works nicely, provided in the link below (which will scroll you to Romas' answer). Basically you hide the file input, and declare another button that you style however you wish.

[In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input#answer-3030174)