# open file dialog via oncontextmenu event

Tags: javascript

I tried to open file dialog by 'oncontextmenu' event, but it didn't work! I can do this by other event, but only 'oncontextmenu' didn't work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function wrapper(ev)
     {
       ev.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById('file').click();
       return false;
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <input id="button" type="button" oncontextmenu="wrapper(event)">
  <input id="file" type="file">

  </body>
</html>
```

I want to know solution or why it doesn't work.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Good question. I reproduced the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dcMY5/4/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because some browsers disallow triggering file input programatically. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) for numerous attempts of this with questionable success.

Comment: Thanks for you question, but I use chrome and I can open file dialog just by click() and other event

Comment: And I can't in Chrome 31.