# How to trigger input click event in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

How can I trigger single click event in IE? It working fine in chrome and FF but not working in IE 8,9,10

My HTML :

```
<div class="qq-uploader">
    <div class="qq-upload-button"
        style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;"
        id="sizcache07400451357324745">
        Click here to upload Image
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 450px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(".qq-upload-button").each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(e){
     $(this).find('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');
     return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Input click trigger is inconsistent across browsers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input). I'd suggest to replace .qq-upload-button div with label, so it'll trigger inner input.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** open fileupload dialog programmatically for a file input element in all browser. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210652/2525067) for more info.

It will be better to do it by [force](http://jsfiddle.net/c6KXg/1/show/) use click on file upload control.

Also you are adding handler to `$(".qq-upload-button")` in each loop, you can add handlers by `on` method at once:

```
$(".qq-upload-button").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).find('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Sorry! it trigger click event but file upload dialog box does not open. why?

Comment: write html code in some other place try once. if it's working problem with css in ie else problem with js. i am not sure try once may be help you

Comment: I edit my answer. You can get more info from this [question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input). I also told you how to do more shorter you code example.

Comment: Sorry! I checked all possibility but id doesn't work.