# Manually trigger click event on other DOM element in knockout viewmodel page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

In my html:

```
<input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/145x145" data-bind="click: imgClick"/>
<input type="file" id="artImage" style="display: none;" />
```

In my viewmodel:

```
var imgClick = function () {
    $("artImage").click();
};
```

If I put a debug breakpoint on the '$("artImage").click()' line, it is hit. I get no error in the console, nothing happens on screen though.

Seems to work ok in a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/nVrSP/ so I'm not sure why it's not working on my page.

(in case anyone asks, I'm trying to do a clickable image to trigger a file upload browse)

Comment: $("input[id='artImage']") is in your fiddle but $("artImage") is in your post... you should probably be using $("#artImage") (ids should be unique)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your selector is probally returning nothing as you have not given it a # to say "this is ID."

try

```
$("#artImage").trigger('click');
```

see this link for list of valid selectors: 
https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/154_cheatsheet/jquery12_colorcharge.png

Comment: [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) "Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element."

Comment: ok thanks @user3334690 .. never used it that way :) ill update answer.

Comment: Nice one, can't believe I missed that obvious one!

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it is a security measure from the vast majority of browsers to **do nothing** on "click" event if the html file input control is **hidden**.

A workaround for this is to hide the file input control using **opacity**, do not hide it using visibility or display=none.

See this thread for more info:

[In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

Comment: Hmm. Well, the solution above worked for me and firefox definitely does allow it (and so does Chrome!).  Thanks for the input though, appreciated.