# OpenFile dialog not working in IE8 using jquery or JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm using an image (and input "file"-->hidden) when user clicks the image it's execute the following code:

```
$('#edtFile1').click(); //edtFile1 is the input for file choose...
```

It's working in FF, chrome and IE>8, in IE8 it's not working, I bind the click to image using jQuery 1.9 with this code:

```
//bind click on image-->file browse      
$("#btnimg1").click(function(event) {
    $('#edtFile1').click();
});
```

Comment: I’d advise to use this solution instead: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not allow the file upload control trigger operation like you did.Instead of you can do like as below.Set File Upload control opacity to 0.

```
<div style="position:relative;display:inline-block;left:-4px;bottom:-6px;width:16px;  height: 24px;overflow:hidden;">
<img src="/images/attach.jpg" alt="" title="Add Attachment" style="height:24px;width:16px; position: relative;top: 1px; left: 0px;"/>
<input type="file" id="fileupload" name="upload" style=" opacity: 0;font-size: 50px;width:16px; filter:alpha(opacity: 0);  position: relative; top: -22px; left: -1px" />
</div>
```

For further reference, please see this. [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input/3030174#3030174)

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/k6zBQ/2/

Comment: Works as expected :-) Thank u very much..:-)))))

Comment: oops it seems that I try it in ie9 but in ie8 doesn't work :-(