# How to trigger jquery input file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger input tag to select a file by a button click though jquery. code example like the following

```
<input type="file" id="input_file"/>

<button onclick="select_file()"/>

function select_file() {
${'input_file').select("http://www.someimage.com/image.gif");
}
```

After hours of research, I still have not got the solution how I could make this happen.

Appreciate for any suggestion or solution

Thanks you

Comment: the file input type is used to select file from local file system...

Comment: Your selector is wrong..you have a curly brace where you need a parenthesis

Comment: @ArunPJohny is correct.  Are you trying to upload a file from the user's computer or are you having the user select an image available online (and then want to upload that image)?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest:

```
$("#input-file").trigger("click");
```

but then I remembered there are security restrictions which prevent triggering and setting the values of file input dialogs.

There are some ways around it though, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030174/992435

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<input type="hidden" id="input_file"/>
<button onclick="select_file()"/>

function select_file() {
 $('input_file').val("http://www.someimage.com/image.gif");
}
```

The input type of file is used mainly for local file system files.

EDIT: Sorry about the typos

Comment: This `${'` should be `$('`. Missed quote, too: `file" />`

Comment: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programatically set to the empty string. ?

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things wrong with your snippet. You were not using script tags, you had forgotten the '#' before ID selectors and you had a curly bracket after the dollar sign.

```
<input type="file" id="input_file/>

<button onclick="select_file()"/>
<script>    
function select_file() {
    $('#input_file').select("http://www.someimage.com/image.gif");
}
</script>
```

Although the way you are approaching your problem technically works, I would never recommend it since it can lead to unmaintainable code. A better approach would be something like:

```
<input type="file" id="input_file/>

<button class="changeInputButton" />
<script>    
$('.changeInputButton').on('click', function () {
  $('#input_file').val("http://www.someimage.com/image.gif");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programatically set to the empty string. ???

Comment: @user2625363 well I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. The warning you are getting is telling you that you can't select a random file in the system file of the user programmatically as it would be a huge security concern

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your codes... correct as follows;

```
<input type="file" id="input_file"/>

<button onclick="select_file()"/>

function select_file() {

   $('#input_file').val("http://www.someimage.com/image.gif");

}
```

1. Use Val in place of Select
2. You missed a # sign in the function
3. You missed a quote in the file input tag
4. You used a curly brace instead of a bracket