# Opening file browser to select file for input type=file triggering on select box option change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open file browser window for input type file, triggering on change on select box option. But it is not working. Any idea what is wrong and how to get it work? FWIW I tried to get an idea from http://jsfiddle.net/afxDC and that is for text field.

*UPDATE:- I found this code works on FF 28.0, but not on chrome 33.0.1750.152 and Safari Version 7.0.3 (9537.75.14). So need to get it work on those browsers too*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      input[type=file] {
        display:block;
        height:0;
        width:0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="item">
      <select id="media-selector">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="image">Add image</option>
          <option value="video">Add video</option>
      </select>
      <input type="file"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#media-selector").change(function() {
        $(this).parents(".item")
          .find('input[type=file]')
          .trigger('click');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution - http://jsfiddle.net/afxDC/33/

jQuery -

```
$('#media-selector').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('.item')
        .find('input[type=file]')
        .trigger('click');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <select id="media-selector">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="image">Add image</option>
        <option value="video">Add video</option>
    </select>
    <input type="file" />
</div>
```

Comment: did it work for you? I visited your jsfiddle too, but I did not find it working.

Comment: It is working for me just fine using FF as the browser. Changing the drop-down opens the file browser.

Comment: I am using chrome Version 33.0.1750.152, and it does not work for me.

Comment: I never checked my solution on FF, I found, even my code works on FF. So the challenge to get it work on Chrome.

Comment: I just tested in Chrome and it works fine. Version 34.0.1847.116, but I'm sure that this would work with earlier versions too. Have you tried any other browsers? I have tested in IE, Chrome, FF and Safari - all work.

Comment: Tried on safari Version 7.0.3 (9537.75.14) , and there too it did not work.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console or other messages that will provide a clue?

Comment: Here is some more info, but some appears to be out-dated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well. But that too did not work. Please note, here if I change select box to text field and then trigger click event on it, then it works. So it is not about style of the file-input field, rather how I can use select box instead input field. As you can see http://jsfiddle.net/afxDC works perfectly. But changing to select box stops working.

Comment: No, it doesn't work perfectly because it places the file name in the text box that is selected.

Comment: in jsfiddle.net/afxDC, ignore the second part where it puts file path in the text field. I updated it , pl. check http://jsfiddle.net/afxDC/35/

Comment: You may have to create something that "looks" like a select box but acts like an input. One thing for sure is that cross-browser / cross-platform is not guaranteed behavior where this is concerned. I found this - http://stiankarlsen.me/blog/fake-jquery-select-list/ which you can modify for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jay. I may have to re-visit my design then. But it is weird that it works perfectly for text field but not for select box :(

Comment: Yeah, it is weird but then again - this is the Interwebs!