# Open file dialog when input type button

Tags: javascript, html

In html we know using input type file we get file dialog to select file. Is there any way to open file dialog using input type button?
We used

```
<input type="file" class="file" name="attachement" />
```

But I want to use

```
<input type="button" class="file" name="attachement" />
```

Comment: answer can see here. It's working [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input/36281035#36281035)

Answer (score 39):

Yes - you can hide the `input type="file"` but still have it in your markup. You then show a regular button on your page and onclick of that button, you programmatically trigger the click event of your actual file input:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display:none;" />
<input type="button" value="Choose Files!" onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();" />
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cnjf50vd/

Comment: @p e p, But I want to avoid input type file in my page.

Answer (score 16):

You can use a button and a hidden file element

```js
function openAttachment() {
  document.getElementById('attachment').click();
}

function fileSelected(input){
  document.getElementById('btnAttachment').value = "File: " + input.files[0].name
}
```

```html
<input type="file" class="file" id="attachment" style="display: none;" onchange="fileSelected(this)"/>
<input type="button" class="file" id="btnAttachment" onclick="openAttachment()" value="File"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

To open a file dialog, you need a file input.

Here you can open it when clicking a button without writing any JavaScript code.

```html
<button type="button">
  <label for="file">
    Open File Dialog
  </label>
</button>
<input type="file" id="file" style="display:none;"/>
```

The point of this solution is to use the `label` element and its `for` attribute.
You should make the label to cover the full button to give a perfect solution.

Comment: This should be the correct solution! Yet there are some issues with the code

Comment: This solution doesn't allow you to open the file modal via keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

U couldn't really open file dialog when the type is a button.. 
U can only use by default type="button" and on mouse over the button, the type will change to type='file' like that :

```html
<input type="button" class="file" name="attachement" onmouseover="(this.type='file')" onmouseout="(this.type='button')" value="Choose file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

no.  the type attribute of input specifies what type of element you are dealing with (IE: checkbox, radio, button, submit, etc), so you have to specifically state file if you want the file dialog to open.  if you want a button, then you specify the input type as a button.

that's not to say you can do workarounds, but setting input type to button is not possible to force a file dialog off that button alone.

Answer (score 0):

Hence I want to avoid type file  in html of a input so I forced to change such type in runtime

```
<input id="fileInput" type="button" style="display:none;" />
<input type="button" value="Choose Files!" onfocus="document.getElementById('fileInput').type='file'" onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> In React this is how is done

```
 const inputer = useRef()
 function ClickComponent(){
   return <div>
       <input ref={inputer} />
       <button onClick={inputer.current.click()}>Click me </button>
   </div>
 }
```

Comment: OP does not seem to use React. This code is equivalent to answers submitted by others in vanilla JS in that it triggers a click event on an `input[type=file]` element.

Answer (score 0):

@Ever answer is better because it doesn't use javascript, but it has some issues as @Shanika said. To function we have to click on the button text, not the button. So I guess we can wrap it all with a label element. But it doesn't work yet. Next, we can wrap the button element with a div element and add `pointer-events:none`.

```html
<label for="fileUpload">
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" style="display:none;" />
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" style="pointer-events:none;" />
  </div>
</label>
```

**EDIT:**

@AgainPsychoX, We can use a custom style for the button if it is possible

```css
button {
    all: unset;

    label {
        padding: 2px 6px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 13.5px;
    }

    &:hover,
    &:focus-within {
        label {
            border: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
            background-color: #e5e5e5;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button>
    <label for="fileUpload2">Upload</label>
</button>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload2" style="display: none" />
```

@Animal Rights, I think we can't go ahead with this approach if we want to use keyboard.

Comment: It also isn't perfect, as button doesn't get :active / :hover events now

Comment: This solution doesn't allow you to open the file modal via keyboard.