# How to simulate a click on a html form through JS and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unity-game-engine

I am developing a unity application that runs on a webpage, I want to upload a file to the server, with unity I can call any javascript function that is on the page.. I've hidden (with CSS) a form with a file input, my goal was to simulate a click on this input so that the open file dialog would open..

this is the form:

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="lol" type="file" name="upl" multiple/>
</form>
```

I tried doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction(){
    //$("#lol").trigger('click');
    $("#lol").click();
    alert("...");
}
</script>
```

neither worked,

I can see the alert.. but no dialog is opened, shouldn't it work? I dont have much experience with JS or Jquery :(

thank you in advance.

EDIT: corrected the element I want (id=lol), it still does not work

Comment: i think open the file dialog is restricted to user only (from browser). You also are not allowed to set file path.

Comment: cant you just call the handler ? $("selector").click();

Comment: Hi Cracker0dks, this is possible without the user.. as the user Rendition posted

Comment: Hi Wardy, I tried that and
$("#lol").trigger('click');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a click event on a file input without a direct user interaction is complicated because of security reasons. Actually it depends on your browser. Chrome for instance requires a visible input field. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) for more information.

So unfortunately a general approach that works on every browser is not possible.

Comment: Oh, I see this one is complicated. Actually It depends on your browser. Chrome for instance requires a visible input field. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) for more information. A general approach for every browser seems not possible because of security reasons :/

Comment: I couldn't find that question before making this one :( well, thank you for the answer zusatzstoff.. If you can, make it an answer so I can accept it, I can't accept the comment as the answer.. thank you for helping.