# Why is this Javascript click function not firing?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="file" name="inputFileElement" id="inputFileElement">

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("inputFileElement").click();
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

I want to fire click Event after 3s.
But this is not working...
It works when `setTimeout(..., 300)`

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It works when timeout is 3ms instead of 3 seconds? Are you doing something on that input field after 300ms ?

Comment: There is nothing  obvious wrong with the above code.

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input-e/210652#210652

Comment: see the link @Toxz provided, you shouldn't trigger a file input programmatically.

Comment: I mean, it is not working at long time such as 3 seconds.

Comment: This code is working. Have you tested it isolated from the rest of code ? It seems not. Error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Toxz gave me correct what i really needed. I'm really appreciated all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/mbqf34hz/

```html
<div id="cl" onclick="alert('click!!!');"></div>
```

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("cl").click();
}, 3000);
```